# F# Excel Range.AutoFilter() fails

Tags: f#, vsto, excel-2010, excel-interop

I'm trying to turn on `AutoFilter` for the users who will consume the data.

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

let xl = ApplicationClass()
xl.Workbooks.OpenText(fileName...)
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)
let ws = wb.ActiveSheet :?> Worksheet

let rows = string ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

// AutoFilter method of Range class failed.
ws.Range("A7:I" + rows).AutoFilter() |> ignore
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: A call with no parameters should just toggle the display of the AutoFilter drop-down arrows, which is all I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter.aspx), you need to pass 5 parameters to `AutoFilter`.

Unspecified parameters can be filled by [System.Reflection.Missing.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.missing.value.aspx).

Something like

```
ws.Range("A7:I" + rows).AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                                   Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, 
                                   System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true) 
|> ignore
```

should work.

Comment: To be fair, both Intellisense and the documentation indicate that all the parameters are optional, and the documentation indicates that omitting all the parameters simply toggles the display of the AutoFilter drop-down arrows, which is what I was after. I had to say that so I didn't feel like a complete idiot. :) `Type.Missing` didn't work on my machine (The namespace or module 'Type' is not defined), so I replaced them with `""`, and it compiled. Unfortunately, it results in the entire range filtered with nothing to display. I also tried `"<>"` per the documentation with the same results.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not familiar with Excel interop. `Type.Missing` should be `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`. I don't know why there's nothing to display, your best bet is changing options and making sure that you have real data to filter.